# How to avoid the apostrophe being escaped in HTML5 input text?

Tags: html, forms, apostrophe

The apostrophe in the user text field is actually being escaped when sending the form. I get the value of the text fields in a PHP page which shows me that the apostrophe is escaped:

For example an original user text input: User `17`'s secret data; the data received through `$_POST` in the PHP receiving page: User `17\`'s secret data.

I suppose that the apostrophe is being replaced by '\' to escape the character when validating the form. How can I avoid this behaviour? (I know, as a person pointed out here) that it is for security reasons, but i'll handle that myself later on.

My form is this one:

```
<form id="form_data" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr style="text-align: left;">
            <th style="width: 150px;">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 150px;">Password</th>
            <th style="width: 200px;">Secrets</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
           <td style="width: 150px;"><input type="text" name="username"></td>
           <td style="width: 150px;"><input type="text" name="password"></td>
           <td style="width: 200px;"><input type="text" name="secrets"></td>
           <td><input id="boton" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

I got the parameter in `insert.php` doing the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['secrets'])) {
   $secrets = $_POST['secrets'];
   $firephp->info($secrets,'secrets: ');
}
```

By the way, as you can see, I tried to get the data displayed in the console using `firephp`, but it will not display it. It might be because the console will just display the data you sent to it in the current page?.

I mean, I send the form's data from `page1` to `page2`(`insert.php`, which inserts the data in a database) and then returns (everything transparent to the user) to `page 1` (which displays the new data in the database) from `page2`, and I just get in the console what I'm sending to it in `page1` but not in `page2`.

Sorry in advance for my english, and thanks a lot!

Comment: You should read up on Cross-Site Scripting (XXS) - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet. A few characters are escaped on inputs to prevent hackers from closing HTML attributes/inputs, and then executing javascript.

Comment: Hi Tricky, Thanks for your answer. I know about that, I meant how to avoid this default behaviour?, I want to keep the apostrophe as it is, so I do not want to be escaped. I've changed the title since It didn't reflected what I wanted to ask whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem myself. I share the solution in case someone is interested in it or having the same problem as mine.

It seems that the 'problem' that is causing the apostrophe to be automatically escaped, it's due to my PHP version (5.2.6); In this version there is a parameter in the php.ini file (magic_quotes_gpc) that when it is turn on causes apostrophes, quotes and backslahes to be escaped in for example (and in my case) the parameters you get from POST or GET global variables; just setting this option off stop the 'issue'.

Regards.